# What is the appropriate output file from T-SQL query of table that has XML as datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I created a batch script that calls a T-SQL file and output it to text file. The T-SQL file contains select statement of a table to get the information of column with XML as datatype. The file will then be sent with either contents as body of email or as an attachment. However, when I open the text file, I see a long list of information similar to the one below:

```
<`EVENT_INSTANCE><EventType>CREATE_INDEX</EventType <PostTime>2009-05-29T12:54:28.463...
```

What I'm expecting is to see contents look like the one below:

```
<EVENT_INSTANCE>
  <EventType>CREATE_INDEX</EventType>
  <PostTime>2009-05-29T12:54:28.463</PostTime>
  <SPID>54</SPID>
  <ServerName>SERVER\INSTANCE</ServerName>
  <LoginName>Domain\username</LoginName>
  <UserName>dbo</UserName>
  <DatabaseName>AdventureWorks</DatabaseName>
  <SchemaName>dbo</SchemaName>
  <ObjectName>ni_ChangeAttempt_DBUser</ObjectName>
  <ObjectType>INDEX</ObjectType>
  <TargetObjectName>ChangeAttempt</TargetObjectName>
  <TargetObjectType>TABLE</TargetObjectType>
  <TSQLCommand>
    <SetOptions ANSI_NULLS="ON" ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT="ON" ANSI_PADDING="ON" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="ON" ENCRYPTED="FALSE" />
    <CommandText>CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ni_ChangeAttempt_DBUser ON
dbo.ChangeAttempt(DBUser)
</CommandText>
  </TSQLCommand>
</EVENT_INSTANCE>
```

If the above is not possible, I expect to see the output of query look like the one below:

```
Event             Post Time                   Server Name
-----             ---------                   -----------

CREATE INDEX      2009-05-29T12:54:28.463     Server\Instance
```

My question is: What is the appropriate output file to which to send the query results so that I can have a more meaningful and more organized view of the results?

ADDITION:

Please see below the contents of the batch script:

```
osql -E -S SERVER\INSTANCE -d <database_name> -iD:\scripts\qryddl.sql -oD:\scripts\qryddl01.txt -w2000 -n -h

bmail -s <ip address> -t <email> -f <email> -h -a " Database Object Changes from <ServerName>" -m D:\scripts\qrydll.txt
```

ADDITION 2:

The qrydll.sql just have this contents:

```
use <database_name>
GO
SELECT EventData FROM dbo.ChangeAttempt
```

The table dbo.ChangeAttempt has this structure:

```
 Column Name     Data Type
 -----------     ---------
 EvenData       xml
 AttemptDate     datetime
 DBUser       char(50)
```

Comment: Don't you think you should show us the script that creates this output?

Comment: Your 'incorrect' XML has some missing characters, like closing brackets and such. Is that the problem you're referring to? Cuz otherwise I can't see where the question is, XML is XML, not some text document.
@John This output is the output of the DDL triggers or the body of an event notifications message.

Comment: @titanium: thanks for the edit. Now please show us the script. Are we meant to guess what the script does?

Answer (score 1):

All you're missing is whitespace, and whitespace is irrelevant to real xml.  Whatever reads that will treat it the same either way.